# Request method 'POST' not supported in Spring Boot any suggestions?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I'm building a web application using Spring Boot and Angular JS which will perform CRUD operations. I have successfully created one class and when implementing this class I'm getting this error "Request method 'POST' not supported"

```
    My controller class is:

        package com.fyp.controller;

        import com.fyp.masterdata.Truck;
        import com.fyp.masterdata.TruckRepository;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
        @RestController
        public class TruckController {

            @Autowired
            TruckRepository truckRepository;


            @GetMapping(value="/truck",  produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public List<Truck> getAll1() {
                List<Truck> list = new ArrayList<>();
                Iterable<Truck> truck = truckRepository.findAll();
                truck.forEach(list::add);
                return list;
            }

            @PostMapping(value="/posttruck")
            public Truck postTruck(@RequestBody Truck truck) {
                truckRepository.save(new Truck(truck.getName(), truck.getCapacity()));
                return truck;
            }

            @GetMapping(value="/getTruckByName/{name}",  produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public List<Truck> getTruckByName(@PathVariable String name) {

                List<Truck> truck = truckRepository.getTruckByName(name);
                return truck;
            }

            @DeleteMapping(value="/truck/{id}")
            public void deleteTruck(@PathVariable long id){
                truckRepository.delete(id);
            }
        }
```

This is the error which I'm getting when I hit the above URL with POST request.

```
    >#2018-05-11 18:42:46.868  WARN 10596 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported
```

This is my front-end Angular JS code which is used to hit the URL. I'm running http://localhost:4200/truck and trying to get it work.

```
    // Get all trucks
      getTruck(): Promise<Truck[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.truckUrl)
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => response.json() as Truck[])
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }
      getTruckByName(name: string): Promise<Truck[]> {
        const url = `/findbytruck/${name}`;
        return this.http.get(url)
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => response.json() as Truck)
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }

      create1(truck: Truck): Promise<Truck> {
        return this.http
          .post("truck", JSON.stringify(truck), {headers : this.headers})
          .toPromise()
          .then(res => res.json() as Truck)
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }

      delete1(id: number): Promise<void> {
        const url = `${this.truckUrl}/${id}`;
        return this.http.delete(url, {headers: this.headers})
          .toPromise()
          .then(() => null)
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }

Thank You.
```

Comment: which url do you use?

Comment: can you show your client side code?

Comment: I have edited the code and put my front end Angular JS code there. Hope it helps

Comment: produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

Comment: It looks like a typo, it probably should be `post("posttruck", JSON.stringify(truck), {headers : this.headers})`  .

Comment: Your POST url is 'truck' not 'posttruck'. Change it to 'posttruck'.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change

`@GetMapping(value="/truck",  produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

to

`@PostMapping(value="/truck",  produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

or

`@RequestMapping(value = "/truck", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there's no problem with the GetMapping the problem is in the PostMapping. But changing POST to GET won't solve it either.